# ssh asking for password; but then "Read from remote host ... Connection reset by peer"

Tags: ssh

When I try to connect to remote server, ssh asks for password, checks it (if I put wrong password it will say "Permission denied") but doesn't let me in:

```
$ ssh user11@123
user11@123's password:
```

nothing happens, and some time later:

```
Read from remote host 123: Connection reset by peer
```

123 is hided server's ip.

Both ssh and sftp do this.

Remote is linux+OpenSSH and week ago ssh worked ok.

in -vvv mode I have after entry of password

```
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

after some time...

```
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 4 w 5 e 6 c -1
Read from remote host 123: Connection reset by peer
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 63 bytes in 117.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.5
```

Comment: Anything in `/var/log/secure` on the server?

Comment: faker, there is no access to the server, it is remote (without remote console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a few different causes of this, there's not enough information here to narrow down the problem exactly.

You'd have to check in your various log files on the server "123" in `/var/log` to see what's going on. This means checking out its console if you can't SSH to it.

An (incomplete) list of possible causes might be:

- Some kind of runaway processes on your server filling up your process table, meaning it can't spawn your shell
- Not enough RAM to spawn a shell.
- Hard disk failure, meaning it can not load your shell from disk even though sshd might still be alive.
- Your login shell set incorrectly to `/bin/false` or something
- Somebody felt it would be funny to `rm -rf /` your server.
- Some script kiddie tried to install a rootkit but botched it up to the degree that a shell won't launch.

Either way you're going to have to go to the console of the server to see what might be going on.

Comment: Server is remote... Does sftp require spawning too? My login was ok week ago; also there is huge time between password accept and disconnect.

Comment: I think sftp will also require some kind of process to be spawned on the server after successful login, but I'm not certain. You might try using `scp` rather than `sftp`, although I'm not sure if that would help. Perhaps you can `scp` down a copy of `/var/log/messages`

Comment: scp don't work too: "... password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
" and nothing happens again. May be disk fault of /var/log/wtmp?

Comment: It might well be a disk fault, although if it were just a disk fault, I'm surprised that logging in still works, perhaps something is caching a copy of /etc/shadow in memory or something. Either way, anything we'll be able to come up like this is just speculation. It could just as well be a hacker attack. Do you have any other services running on the machine, or does it only do SSH?

Comment: Per von Zweigbergk, as I know there is only SSH accessible from internet. There are internal services like webserver. And any access to internal network is only via this server.

Comment: Finally got here. Load average is 13 14 25. I think it was > 50. 123 Zombie processes

Comment: Also, there was very active disk access by internal tasks